# JavaScript updating a global variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global, updating

I am currently not the most experienced in Javascript and I'm trying to learn bit by bit. Anyway... how do I update the balance variable more efficiently?

Currently I believe I am doing this wrong.  Also my button does not work on click event.

Anything would be a massive help! Thank you.

```
// Set global variables
var name;
var balance;
var weed;

// Ask the user his name for his character
name = window.prompt("What is your name?", "Cap'n Grow");
var finalName = document.getElementById('name');
finalName.textContent = name;


// Set the balance to default
balance = 100;
var FinalBalance = document.getElementById('balance');
FinalBalance.textContent = balance;

// Set the balance of weed to default 
weed = 10;
var FinalWeed = document.getElementById('gear');
FinalWeed.textContent = weed;

// Sell function
function sellGear() {
    var check = window.prompt("Are you sure you want to sell 5 bags?", "Yes");
    if (check === 'Yes' && weed >= 5) {
        console.log("Transaction was successful!");
        // Update the balance
        var updBalance = document.getElementById('balance');
        updBalance.textContent = balance + 150;
    } else {
        console.log("Failed!")
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <div class="dashboard">
                    <div id="name"></div>
                    <div id="balance"></div>
                    <div id="gear"></div>
                    <div id="sell">
                        <button id="sellButton" onlick="sellGear()">Sell?</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be `onclick` not `onlick`

Comment: But, now there's no event for when I lick my phone :(

Comment: onlick lol you made my day. I am also assuming your JavaScript code is in `<script>` tags, you posted combined with HTML for demonstration, right? Or does your file look like this?

Comment: +1 because your weed selling script made me laugh so hard. Love it.

Comment: lol I've fixed it now. But once I click the sell I've got it to also deduct and update by -5 each time. However I can't go any lower. The javascript file is separate yes, it's not in script tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution and a suggestion:
Try to use java script code at the end of your HTML.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <div class="dashboard">
                    <div id="name"></div>
                    <div id="balance"></div>
                    <div id="gear"></div>
                    <div id="sell">
                        <button id="sellButton" onclick="return sellGear();">Sell?</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</html>

<SCRIPT>
// Set global variables
var name;
var balance;
var weed;

// Ask the user his name for his character
var name = window.prompt("What is your name?", "Cap'n Grow");
var finalName = document.getElementById('name');
finalName.textContent = name;

// Set the balance to default
var balance = 100;
var FinalBalance = document.getElementById('balance');
FinalBalance.textContent = balance;

var weed = 10;
var FinalWeed = document.getElementById('gear');
FinalWeed.textContent = weed;

// Sell function
function sellGear() {
  var check = window.prompt("Are you sure you want to sell 5 bags?", "Yes");
    if (check === 'Yes' && weed >= 5) {
        console.log("Transaction was successful!");
        // Update the balance
        var updBalance = document.getElementById('balance');
        updBalance.textContent = balance + 150;
    } else {
        console.log("Failed!")
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Well before in my sell function I just had balance = balance = 50; However this doesn't increment my balance when I press sell, how come? thank you

Comment: you were using "onlick" instead of "onclick"  
 <button id="sellButton" onlick="sellGear()">Sell?</button>
:)

and it's my pleasure to help you..